# Post Tax Traditional IRA vs Normal Mutual Funds Account

Tags: united-states, ira, retirement

I am setting up a Traditional IRA account and this will have my **post tax** contributions. Traditional IRA does not have any income limit but the contribution limit is $6000 (married filling jointly).

If the same funds are available as a normal mutual funds account (Non-Retirement) then is there any reason to even use a post tax traditional IRA account? A normal mutual funds account also does not have any contribution or income limits.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you considered converting funds from the Traditional IRA to Roth IRA?

Comment: I thought about it but I will have to pay tax on that now and that will even push me into a different income bracket.

Comment: Unless you have pre-tax funds in Traditional/SEP/SIMPLE IRAs, you will not have to pay tax for conversion to Roth IRA, since you are converting all post-tax funds.

Comment: I have funds that are pre-tax in traditional IRA since it is a rollover 401K from my employer. My future contributions to traditional IRA will be post tax.

Comment: FYI, the usual terms used to describe IRA contributions are "deductible" and "non-deductible", not "pre-tax" and "post-tax".

Comment: @MehreenAzam: Does your current 401k allow rollover from IRA? If it does, you can rollover all the pre-tax amounts into your 401k, leaving only post-tax amounts in the Traditional IRA, which will allow you to convert to Roth IRA without paying tax.

Comment: @user102008 that's a fantastic idea. I think the norm is the other way around (roll 401K into IRA) to get better choices and lower fees, but in this case, if it enables getting tax free gains on 6-12K contributions per year, forever, moving the IRA back into the 401k is definitely something to consider.

Comment: @user102008 Are you sure that one can rollover _only_ the pretax contributions (and earnings thereon) into a 401(k) plan? Generally speaking, money leaving a Traditional IRA must be prorated between the pretax portion and the post-tax portion, and the last post-tax contribution comes out when the last of _all_ Traditional IRA accounts is closed.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think the answer is you can't, even though the comment is worded as if you can. But, I got the impression that OP currently has *only* pretax in the traditional IRA, and is about to do non-deductible contributions for the first time. So OP could potentially zero it out first, and then start making non-deductible contributions.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Yes. See Publication 590-A section "[Kinds of rollovers from a traditional IRA](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a#en_US_2020_publink1000230575)". Rollovers from Traditional IRA to a qualified plan can only include pre-tax amounts. Without a special rule, this means that Traditional IRA with post-tax amounts (basis) cannot be rolled over to qualified plan, due to the pro-rata rule. A special rule allows this rollover by treating amounts rolled over as only including pre-tax amounts, though the wording is unclear as to whether it applies to 401k.

Answer (score 8):

There are some distinct **advantages** of putting your *first* $6K of funds per year into a Non-Deductible IRA, compared to putting that same amount into a normal investment account:

1. Like both the Traditional and Roth IRAs, taxes are deferred. With a non-retirement account you have to pay taxes each year that you have realized capital gains.
2. You have the ability to transfer those funds into a Roth IRA, and from that moment on you'll have no taxes due on any of the gains. There is a Pro-Rata rule that dictates how much of the rollover is taxable, but generally if you don't have a lot of funds already in a Traditional IRA, then it usually makes sense to immediately roll funds sitting in a non-deductible IRA over to a Roth. This is oftentimes called a "backdoor Roth" because it enables contributing to a Roth even if you aren't eligible to *directly* contribute to a Roth.
3. Under most circumstances IRAs are protected from bankruptcy, up to a limit. Regular investment accounts are not.

The **disadvantages** of the Non-Deductible IRA compared to a brokerage account are:

1. There is a 10% penalty on the taxable portion of any withdrawals you make before the age of 59.5.
2. There is some extra documentation needed for non-deductible contributions ([Form 8606](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8606).) If somehow you forgot to fill out the form, then later when you withdraw those after-tax contributions they may be subject to taxation again. Additionally, in theory you may have to save those forms for many years until all the money is withdrawn from the account. Though, perhaps if you roll the Non-Deductible IRA funds into a Roth you wouldn't need to continue to keep the records indefinitely, since no part of Roth distributions would normally be taxable in the future.

Weighing these Pros and Cons, if you are going to move the Non-Deductible IRA into the Roth, then it's probably a no-brainer to put your first $6K per year into the after-tax IRA.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes. I would go with Traditional IRA and keep track of Form 8606. I use Turbo Tax so I will need to print it out for each year starting 2022.

Comment: "There may be penalties if you later decide to withdraw more than your contributions (i.e. some of your gains) before the age of 59.5" There are actually taxes and penalties even if you decide to withdraw less than your contributions before the age of 59.5, as long as there are any gains, since any withdrawal from Traditional IRA will withdraw from both pre-tax and post-tax parts.

Comment: @user102008 Agreed- the penalty would apply to *some* amount (unless the account unfortunately had at most the sum of the non-deductible contributions) . I updated the answer. I left out the mention of taxes though since it's comparing with a non-retirement account, which would also be taxable. Thx!

Comment: I use Turbo Tax for filing my taxes and I hope Form 8606 is available on Turbo Tax to make my life easier. So, if I am married filling jointly and contributing $6000 (myself) and $6000 (spouse) then I have to write in 8606 the amount $12,000. This should indicate that I don't have to pay taxes on $12,000 since I already paid them.

Comment: @MehreenAzam I'm pretty sure the form is available in Turbo Tax, though it may not always be available immediately in January. Also, I think you have to fill out the form for each person, even if married filling jointly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TTT

Comment: @MehreenAzam Your wife and you have to file _individual_  Forms 8606 both of which will accompany your joint return. That is, you don't declare $12,000 on one form but rather $6000 on two separate Forms 8606. TurboTax knows about this and will create two Forms 8606 for you.

Answer (score 1):

All IRA contributions are "post-tax" money going in. It's whether or not you get a tax **deduction** in the contribution year. There are [income limits for the deduction](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/ira-deduction-limits), depending on your work retirement plan options.

You cannot deduct your taxable income with brokerage account contributions / purchasing of mutual funds (or ETFs, or individual stocks/bonds) in that account.

If you are below the income limits of a Roth IRA and don't want to pay taxes on future gains (as you would with a brokerage account), then you should prefer a Roth IRA over a traditional.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. OP is specifically asking about *after-tax* contributions to a Traditional IRA, which is different from the typical pre-tax contributions you're referring to in your answer. It's generally for people that can't contribute directly to Roth, but also have a retirement plan at work and aren't eligible to take the tax deduction for Traditional IRA contributions.

Comment: @TTT as written, **all** IRA contributions are made with after tax dollars. It's done with money after your employer takes out medical, federal tax, etc. It's the deduction / tax credit that gets refunded to fill in the gap. The question said nothing about backdoor IRA contributions or income limits

Comment: I think the point you're making in your first sentence is semantics, and I agree with that. But when talking about retirement plans, the term "after-tax" or "post-tax" has a special meaning, which is, you won't be able to take a deduction for it. That's why your answer doesn't apply to this question. The question assumes OP isn't eligible for either a tax-deductible traditional IRA or a Roth. That's why OP is exploring the lesser known third option.

Comment: There's no effective difference between pre-tax contributions and getting a deduction for after-tax contributions. Either way you don't pay tax on the contribution.

Comment: @Barmar and that is exactly why in the accounting world, no one ever says "after tax" or "post-tax" for something that is deductible.

Comment: Accountants have to watch how the money actually moves through the system, so the distinction matters to them. But to the taxpayer it makes no difference. But you're right, the IRS terminology for IRAs refers to deductible and non-deductible contributions. I pointed it out to the OP in as comment. But the terminology makes no difference regarding the decision whether to fund an IRA.

Comment: @Barmar note the IRS uses the terms "after-tax" as well to refer to non-deductible. [Example here.](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/rollovers-of-after-tax-contributions-in-retirement-plans) (I'm not sure if the IRS ever calls it "post-tax" though.)

Comment: @TTT That is an "after-tax" 401K, though, which was not originally mentioned by OP

Comment: @OneCricketeer Is this really a good hill to die on? (Hehe- just kidding, I do the same thing sometimes.) I thought we were talking  about the definition of "after-tax", regardless of vehicle, right? Anyway, also on that same page you'll see this text too "after-tax contributions to a traditional IRA". Pretax and After-tax are definitely distinguished; that's just the words we use when discussing such things.